# Can exception/error in one thread halt the whole application?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, error-handling

If an error / exeption is thrown in a thread (not a main one) can this halt the whole application ?

Is there such possibility ? Or will this just stop the thread it was running in ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If an error / exeption is thrown in a thread (not a main one) can this halt the whole application ?

It will if it causes the only non-daemon thread to return from `run()`

If there are other non-daemon threads running or the exception or error is caught and handled, the application will keep running.

> will this just stop the thread it was running in ?

if the exception or error is caught and handled it might not stop any threads.

Comment: thx :) So a typical thread is a non-daemon type ? I have to turn a thread into a deamon ?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change whether a thread is daemon once it has started. You can start new threads as daemons.

Comment: Is the main thread special in any way ? What will happen if there are 2 threads running and an unhandled exception is thrown in main one ?

Comment: @peter if non daemon throws runtimeException  which is not handled by that thread..so program should be  stop execeuting other threads( main thread) ??

Comment: @saurabh If the only non-daemon thread throws an Error or Exception which is not handled, stopping that thread, then it will shutdown the process. i.e. an error or exception only stop one thread at most, but if that is the last non-daemon thread, it can shutdown the program.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Peter Lawrey's answer, there's one more case when unhandled exception can cause application freeze: if died thread had grabbed some lock needed by other threads of program.

Comment: Yeah - kinda depends on what is meant by 'halt' - process closed or process threads deadlocked.

Comment: If your application has been coded correctly, resource locks should be freed. If you release your locks incorrectly, it could be the source of the error in which case it quite likely to cause more problems. ;)